# Bat File to Read Flag

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to create a bat file to read a flag from a text file and if flag is there execute my Java program if not stop processing.

Bellow is a sample text file.

```
PORT_DATA|540387
NDB_AML_AA|43539
NDB_AML_LD|12884
NDB_AML_REPO|441
NDB_AML_TRAN|617908
NDB_AML_JOINT_AC|213660
NDB_AML_CUS_REL_PRTY|43
NDB_AML_BICCODE|108291
CUSTOMER_MASTER|670807
CATEGORY.MASTER|3280
DEPT.MASTER|2426
COUNTRY.MASTER|251
CUSTOMER.STATUS.MASTER|26
INDUSTRY.MASTER|65
JOB.TITLE.MASTER|22
COMPANY.MASTER|115
TRANSACTION.MASTER|782
SECTOR.MASTER|16
RELATION.MASTER|56
EOF
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you provide some more information, that will be useful

Comment: What kind of information you require?

Comment: @DeE DEe check if my answer suites your need.

Comment: what flag? Only check, if it's present? Or do you need the number?

Comment: What is the flag? Is the word `EOF` actually in your file? Why doesn't `EOF` have a number after it? Come on, make an effort to ask your question properly if you want folks to help you.

Comment: EOF means End Of File and it should not have a number since it means "End Of File". EOF is a common flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly , when a EOF is found at the last line of your input text you need to run your java program ,

find if EOF is the last line of your text file and if yes execute java else exit

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do set Lastline=%%A
if "EOF" == "%Lastline%" goto prog
goto last
:prog
<run your java prog here>
:last
echo "end script"
```

Comment: When I execute the output is always end script, and the Java program is not running.  What it means by if "EOF" == "%last%" goto prog
goto last
:prog?

Comment: here input.txt is the file which contains the sample date , which you showed above , now the for loop reads this data and then assigns the last line to a variable last , if the file contains last line as EOF then the if condition is successful and it will go to java step , if it is not the script will end. make sure you are pointing to correct data , please feel free to revert with your concerns.

Comment: thanks, seems like i have used two different variables , now i have corrected it , please refer to above updated code , now this should work , i have tested from my end.

Comment: How can I display a msg on cmd that the process is started?

Comment: after the tag :prog , you can add echo statement , which will tell you java process has started.

Comment: if the solution is helpful please vote up and accept , this will be helpful to other searching for same problem

Comment: If Condition is unsuccessful it goes to :last?

Comment: Above code uses labels which means, if File contained EOF it will goto :proc and then executes java program , Now let's say your file did not contain EOF at the end of file ,  above code will goto last part of the script , thereby stop processing i.e this will not run java program.

Comment: How to compare the first line in text file=sysdate=1? Date format is DD-MON-YYYY format